# In following program, what is the purpose of the while loop?

Tags: java

There are no problems with the compilation, but whether or not I have the while loop in place or not, the result is the same. I can't understand why the while loop is included. BTW, this is just an example program from the Java SE tutorial:

```
public class ContinueWithLabelDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
        String substring = "sub";
        boolean foundIt = false;

        int max = searchMe.length() - substring.length();

        test:
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            int n = substring.length();
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;

            while (n-- != 0) { // WTF???
                if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                    continue test;
                }
            }

            foundIt = true;
            break test;
        }
        System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
    }
}
```

Comment: `n` is counting down from the `substring.length()` to `0`

Comment: @MadProgrammer normally yes but `continue test;` inside `while` makes it not that easy...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don think so, b/c then it would only run this loop 3 times, but it does keep going until the substring is found (or not). Also, if I take the while loop out (including the proper braces), the result of the program is the same. There must be some valid reason why they put it in.

Comment: @pshemo But that's just pushing back to the start of the outside loop, so `n` is begin recalculated back to `substring.length()`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Exactly, so the length stays the same (in this case, 4). They only affect is whether there is a match, or if it completes the outer for loop.

Comment: Remove the while loop and see what problem it causes. It might give you a clue

Comment: @JeroenVanneval Already did that, and it is exactly the same. I guess it's  just extraneous. I assumed that since it was in the Oracle Java SE tutorial for Branching Statements, there must have been a valid reason for it...maybe not.

Comment: change substring from "sub" to "ccc", you will find the result is different if you don't have while loop inside.

Comment: @yushulx Sorry, but it still does the same thing. The result is just different. It says "Didn't find it," b/c ccc is not in the searchMe String, so that's okay. It's supposed to do that, and gives the same "Didn't find it" whether or not while loop is there.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry, I just looked at what the question was, in some vain hope we could get more from the OP...Personally, `labels` are a sign of bad design and should be avoid - IMHO :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agree that in most cases labels can be avoid but sometimes they can also be used to produce readable and quite optimized code. They are like atomic energy, it all depends in which hands we put it :)

Comment: @ManavMisra It's not just about returning the correct result for a given set of data - a program should return the correct (expected) result for **all** possible sets of data. This is very important and overlooking it can result in seriously buggy programs. When you take out the while loop here, it may work for your current input string, but it may not work as expected for every possible input string (some may fail). When we cannot cover all cases, we would try to cover the all the obvious types of cases like Pshemo does, as much as we can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your

```
while (n-- != 0) { // WTF???
```

with

```
System.out.println("outside loop");
while (n-- != 0) { // WTF???
    System.out.println("inside loop: comparing "
            + searchMe.charAt(j) + ":" + substring.charAt(k));
```

to see how this example works. Below is little explanation.

---

This code is searching for `substring` in `searchMe` string. Take a look at this example:

```
Look for a substring in me
^
sub
```

If you compare characters at position 0 in `searchMe` and `substring` you will notice that they are not the same `L` != `s` so we can skip matching rest of letters and go to next position (that is the purpose of `continue test;`)

```
Look for a substring in me
 ^
 sub
```

So now we will try compare next letter with first letter of `searchMe` with first letter of `substring`. This time we get `o`!=`s` so there is no way that substring starts in this place, lets carry on.

After few comparisons we finally found promising place

```
Look for a substring in me
           ^
           sub
```

where first letter of `substring` is the same as current letter in `searchMe` (`s`==`s`) so we wont jump from `while` loop yet and will try to check next letter. And we have another success

```
Look for a substring in me
            ^
           sub
```

because `u`==`u`, so we will continue our loop until we iterate over our entire `substring` which can happen in next step.

```
Look for a substring in me
             ^
           sub
```

And this time we compared `b` with `b`. Since they are equal and we don't have more letters in `substring` to check we can set value of `foundIt` to `true` and brake `test` for loop.

And that is the end.

---

If you remove while from your code you will get positive response as soon as you will find first character that will match first letter of `substring` in your case in after checking `Look for a` program will match `s` with first letter on `substring` which will also be `s`.

While loop is used here to iterate over entire `substring` and only in case of fail in matching corresponding characters we will move searching one place forward. If we would ignore this inner loop and just iterate over entire data we can ignore some positive results like in case where we would look for `aab` in `aaab` String. Take a look

```
aaab
aab
^^
```

`^` will match but after them we will have to match `a` with `b` which will fail. Without inner while loop we would probably start another match from last checked position that failed which would be

```
aaab
  aab
  ^
```

This time we also failed to find match for substring so we skipped `a*aab*` part.